# Debian mysql-proxy reserved connections

Tags: linux, debian, unix, mysql

I was looking in too the mysql-proxy configuration, and decied to install it in order to make an access point to my servers whenever they reach high peak, however i want to have 5-10 reserved connection to my servers, but i dont see that in the configuration ( or perhaps i didn't find it yet ). Is there a method or a tool that can keep 5-10 connections (persistent) reserved and open on the mysql servers so that i can acess at anytime ?

Thanks,
Alin

Comment: you mean connections to the database or to the server hosting the database?

Comment: connections to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to make mysql-proxy reserved connection with ro-pooling.lua.
Just add ro-pooling.lua plugin to mysql-proxy and it worked.
[ro-pooling.lua](https://github.com/cwarden/mysql-proxy/blob/315ab806bb95b8223f5afd3d238eff2a40af03d8/lib/ro-pooling.lua)

Contact me if you need help on  this